# is spring boot server required start to fetch data from database? as i am working in spring boot JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, server

I am trying to fetch data from my database and at the same time I also want to know if I can access my controllers or any request mapped path but I am not unable to do the same. what could be wrong ?
I am a noob at this you can judge me and can help me at the same time

I am using IntelliJ IDEA comm. edition and I am trying to make a simple REST API to get much more hand on exposure on CRUD. I am using mysql work bench for database connection and I have tried to fetch data from database while spring boot server were not running now if I am trying to run spring boot server so that i can see my other request mapped path output then it is throwing error like:

> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
>   Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
>   to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no
>   profiles are currently active).

with "Process finished with exit code 1" server is getting stopped immediately.

how to fix this?

My spring-boot application function code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```

My database connection for hibernate in spring boot JPA, name `persistence.xml` which is correct as far as I know.

Update as per recent request for my pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit-dep -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>     <!-- NOT org.junit here -->
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here is persistence.xml file which drive me to connect java and database in intellij

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="firstest">
      <properties>
         <!-- Configuring The Database Connection Details -->
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/firstschema" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: please add your pom.xml file

Comment: i don't think there is anything missing in my pom.xml file

Comment: did you add jpa and db setting in application.properties / yaml file?

Comment: @suv1sh `pom.xml` seems correct please also add database connection settings.

Comment: @Subramanya, no, i didn't change anything on those files. right now application.properties is empty by default and yaml file is unknown to me.

Comment: Yes, you need to add database connection properties to the application.properties or application.yml file. Then your application will be able to connect to the db

Comment: @MuhammadUsman i have added the percsistence.xml file thet lead me to database connection. i have done several fetching of data from my database by that method

Comment: @Subramanya, i have done multiple data fetching by persistence.xml (which connect database *mysql workbench* to java) , then how would application.properties gonna help me for the same? as i am able to fetch datas but not able to access my request mapped path even my spring boot server is not getting start it is getting stopped immediately.

Comment: @suv1sh spring boot is not able to search `persistence.xml` by default. Are you defining your custom been for using `persistence.xml`?

Comment: @Subramanya, thanks man it worked for me.
also thank to MuhammadUsman's effort